# how to access javascript in a pdf field under c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf

I want to access java script validations applied on fields of PDF document. Is there any existing library for the same? I have used following code snippet to access individual field javascript (in C#):

```
 using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile.FileContent))
            {  
                AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
                for (int page = 0; page < reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> fieldEntity in form.Fields)
                    {
                        switch ((PdfFieldTypes)form.GetFieldType(fieldEntity.Key))
                        {
                            case PdfFieldTypes.CHECKBOX:
                            case PdfFieldTypes.COMBO:
                            case PdfFieldTypes.LIST:
                            case PdfFieldTypes.RADIOBUTTON:
                            case PdfFieldTypes.TEXTFIELD:
                               //Some logic
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This code is working perfectly fine for normal pdf files but doesn't seem to work for locked version of pdf files (locked, as in not open for writing in any pdf writer or designer). Is there a way to read field javascript for locked pdfs?

Comment: *locked, as in not open for writing in any pdf writer or designer* - do you mean flattened forms?

Comment: yes,kind of flattened forms

Comment: *flattened forms* aren't AcroForm forms anymore, they merely still look like forms. Thus, there are no AcroForm form fields to access programmatically, and as a consequence there also is no JavaScript associated with AcroForm form fields anymore.